# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getDefaultChain')

Tags: web3js, react, walletconnect, etherjs, wagmi-react

in this code when i want call the function from contract i get this error: **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getDefaultChain')**
i use walletConnect V2 for connecting wallet and use etherjs for connecting to contract

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPrecardId = async () => {
      if (contract) {
        try {
          const preCardId = await contract.functions.functionName();
          setPreCardId(preCardId);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(`error: ${error}`);
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Contract object is undefined or null");
      }
    };

    fetchPrecardId();
  }, []);
```

Comment: I'm also getting the same error and I'm using [@web3modal/standalone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@web3modal/standalone), which is recently deprecated. Not sure if I have to move to the [@walletconnect/modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@walletconnect/modal) to fix this.